# Kentico Language Packs

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

I need to change Kentico date format to dd/MM/yyyy. I tried following the settings here
https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/configuring-kentico/reference-web-config-application-keys#ReferenceWeb.configapplicationkeys-Userinterfaceculturesettings

but looks like I'm gonna need a CMS.resx pack. Where do I get this language pack for Australia (en-AU)?

Answer (score 0):

The language packs are available for download on the [Devnet portal](https://devnet.kentico.com/download/localization-packs). However, in case of EN-AU, if you do not require translation of the resource strings to the Australian English (I guess the EN-AU is pretty much the same as EN-US in this case), you can simply copy the CMS.resx file and rename it CMS.en-au.resx.
Or, you can use the **CMSDefaultUICulture** web.config key and set the default UI culture to EN-AU and then, the system will take the CMS.resx as the EN-AU culture's resource file. For more details please see the d[ocumentation on setting up multilingual UI](https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/multilingual-websites/setting-up-a-multilingual-user-interface).